# Updating a Redux Store within a useEffect() Hook. useSelector to returns old information and useDispatch doesn't update the store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, setinterval

I'm working on a React App that shows an image and logs user's keystrokes. Everything is working fine until the client asks for the images to change automatically after 4 seconds of no user input.

I decided to use `setInterval()` within the `useEffect()` react hook to achieve this. It works fine.

However, I am not able to update or even retrieve data reliably from the Redux Store inside the `useEffect()` hook.

### REDUX CODE:

```
const nBackStateDispatch = (dispatch) => ({
  newNBackState: (users) => dispatch(newNBackState(users)),
});  

const { newNBackState } = nBackStateDispatch(useDispatch());

const NBackState = useSelector(
    (state) => state.examNavigationReducer.newNBackState
  );
```

### Use EFFECT CODE

```
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    newNBackState(NBackState)
    console.log("This will run every four seconds!");
  }, 4000);
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [NBackState]);
```

I can update the redux store using hooks I built into buttons, but the `useSelector()` hook in `useEffect()` returns the default redux store value while a `useSelector()` hook in a separate component outside `useEffect` returns the updated value.

Here are the expected inputs and outputs for the function and store:

### INPUTS AND EXPECTED OUTPUTS

**Redux Store** Initial state:
NBackState = 0

**Expected** useDispatch() Output:
NBackState++

**Actual** Output outside useEffect()
NBackState++

**Actual** Output inside useEffect()
NBackState

**Expected** useSelector() Output
NBackState = 1

**Actual** Output outside useEffect()
NBackState = 1

**Actual** useSelector() Output
NBackState = 0

**Redux Store** state after useDispatch():
NBackState = 1

Answer (score 0):

Your redux code is really bizarre.  You are combining the responsibilities of actions and selectors.

You should be dispatching an action to update the state and using a `useSelector` hook to read the current value of the state.

It should look something like this:

```
const MyComponent = () => {

  const nBackState = useSelector(
    (state) => state.examNavigationReducer.newNBackState
  );

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      dispatch(incrementNBackState());
      console.log("This will run every four seconds!");
    }, 4000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

/*...*/
```

Where `incrementNBackState` is an action creator function.  Your reducer will respond to the `incrementNBackState` action by modifying the value of `newNBackState`.

[**Here is a functioning demo.**](https://codesandbox.io/s/setinterval-with-react-redux-q93f5q?file=/src/components/App.tsx)

Comment: Thank you Linda,   

On my next project I'm planning to implement redux slices.  Its so much tidier. 

I'm humbled by how quickly you made that mockup.  It was incredibly useful to learn how to implement redux slices properly.   

In the end useEffect() worked as expected.  The issue was that my console.log calls were working inside the useEffect() function.  When I moved them to the main body of the .js file outside the useEffect() function things worked as expected.

Thanks again!  

Stephan

p.s. Do you think the code will stay up on code pen for a while?

Comment: @StephanDuVal yes, I keep things in my CodeSandbox account indefinitely.  I have a [template for a react-redux counter](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-counter-example-wnq4h) that I fork for a lot of answers, that's how I can make a demo so quickly :)